# Correlation between Independent Set and Matching

Tags: algorithm, graph, matching, independent-set

Assume we have an undirected Graph G = (V,E) and we construct a new Graph G' where two nodes are adjacent if they have a common neighbor node in G.
Can someone explain why the following statements are true if we have such a construction G'?

If G has an independent set of size n, then G' has a matching of size n.
If G' has an matching of size n, then G has an independent set of size n.

Unfortunately I don't have an idea for this problem

Comment: "...where two nodes are adjacent if they have a common node in G", what does that mean? Do you mean "if they have a common neighbor in G"?

Comment: Oh yes I mean neighbor

Comment: Do you have some other assumption about the graph? Maybe something about connectivity? Otherwise, consider a graph G with n nodes and no edges. The set of all nodes in G is an independent set and clearly there are no edges in G', so also no matching of size > 0.